# Angular JS: Directive content is not available in Java script function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `div` which has `ng-click`. When I click on that `div`, it calls a function which gets script content from a Directive and I append that to another `div` and access the content of the script. But when I retrieve the content of the directive I am getting directive name not the content. I want to get the content.

The function I call:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(){
  var appendHtml = $compile("<my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive>")($scope);
  $("#someId").append(appendHtml)
  //But when i append I am seeing as <my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive> in html not the actual content

  $(""#someId"").find('script')
}
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('myCustomDirective', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/somecontent.html',
    replace: true,
    link: function ($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {}
  };
});
```

Somecontent.html

```
<script type="text/template">
  <div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
    some elements here
  </div>
</script>
```

The HTML where I call from:

```
<div ng-click="someFunction()">
  <div id="someId">
    <my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive> 
    //But Here I am seeing this, when calling 
    $(appendHtml).find('script') in my javascript function, after Javasciprt function call is done, It works fine. But i want to see actual content here when calling $(""#someId"").find('script')
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good practice.

you can use ng-if and binding instead , like the follwing:

HTML

```
<div ng-click="someFunction()">
  <div id="someId">
    <div ng-if="$scope.isVisible">
          <my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive> 
    </div>
    //But Here I am seeing this, when calling 
    $(appendHtml).find('script') in my javascript function, after Javasciprt function call is done, It works fine. But i want to see actual content here when calling $(""#someId"").find('script')
  <div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
 $scope.isVisible = false;

$scope.someFunction = function(){
   $scope.isVisible = true;
}
```

you can also pass isolate scope param to your directive and check the param in the directive template

Comment: I am getting the content on demand when someFunction is called. So your soltuion doesn’t work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're just not using jQuery or jqLite to select elements correctly.

Your `someFunction` might need to look more like this:

```
vm.someFunction = function () {
  var appendHtml = $compile('<my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive')($scope);
  angular.element(document).find('some-id-element').append(appendHtml);
};
```

I put together [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/i5rvR7IMGZsr34q7LOrF?p=preview) that I think might achieve what you're trying to do.

Does this approximate your goal?

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i need to use the content that is appended  within the same java script function. For example i want to use the script that is appended in the same function. Like, angular.element(document).find('some-id-element').find('script'). To add more after i append that directive, i need to popup that added directive.